# NextJS Image gives a weird positioning

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am trying to change my standard `<img/>` to the NextJS `<Image/>` but I cannot find why my images are not rendered properly.

This is the basis  tag

```
<div className=" mx-auto sm:w-9/12 lg:w-7/12 xl:w-8/12">
  <img
  className="object-fill rounded-md mx-auto sm:w-9/12 lg:w-full xl:w-8/12"
  src={img}
  alt="something"
/>
</div>
```

this works perfectly

[image]

While using the NextJS Image it does not work correclty

```
<div className=" mx-auto sm:w-9/12 lg:w-7/12 xl:w-8/12">

 <Image
  src={img}
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="contain"
  alt="something"
  className="rounded-md mx-auto w-full"
></Image>
</div>
```

[image]

All I can see it that the outer div of the `<Image/>` itself takes the width of the whole div (text + image) because the parent div of the `<Image/>` has apparently no width or height, while it has w-7/12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `position:relative` to the parent div

Answer (score 0):

You can try use a div as a container for style the Image component.

```
<div className=" mx-auto sm:w-9/12 lg:w-7/12 xl:w-8/12">
<div  className="rounded-md mx-auto w-full">
 <Image
  src={img}
  layout="fill"
  objectFit="contain"
  alt="something"
/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, sadly this does not help, the <Image> div still takes the width of the text + image instead of the image width